# Work with Actions Class in TESTNG-POM Framework in Selenium JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am Stuck in between of code during implementation of Actions class I am Getting **NullpointerException** on Double Click of **checkbox** record
Below is my Selenium Code

```
package Script;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class DriverInstance {
    public WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("https://ppmss360.ford.qa.ams.hpmsdynamics.com");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
  //driver.quit();
  }

}
```

Below is TestNGScript class :

```
package Script;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import POM.Acc_landingPage_Pom;
import POM.Dashboard_POM;
import POM.LoginCRM;

public class OpenAccount extends DriverInstance {

  @Test
  public void f() throws InterruptedException {


        Acc_landingPage_Pom obj1 = new Acc_landingPage_Pom(driver);
        obj1.rec_open();


  }
}
```

Below is POM Class :

```
    package POM;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Acc_landingPage_Pom {
    public WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(xpath="(//input[@class='ms-crm-RowCheckBox'])[1])")
    private WebElement acc_rec;

    public Acc_landingPage_Pom(WebDriver driver2) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver2, this);

    }
        public void rec_open()
        { 



            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.moveToElement(acc_rec).doubleClick().perform();
        }
}
```

getting **NullPointerException** on Actions Line in rec_open() method .

Below is NPE stackTrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.<init>(Actions.java:44)
    at POM.Acc_landingPage_Pom.rec_open(Acc_landingPage_Pom.java:24)
    at Script.OpenAccount.f(OpenAccount.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone Look into this

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? Are you trying to figure out why you're getting a `NullPointerException`? If so, can you provide the full stack trace? If not, can you please clarify what your question is? Thanks.

Comment: @mfulton26 yeah i want to figure out where and why i am getting Issue. added stackprinttrace

Answer (score 0):

`Acc_landingPage_Pom.driver` is `null` which is why when attempting to construct an `Actions` instance your are getting a `NullPointerException`

I don't see anywhere where you initialize `driver` in `Acc_landingPage_Pom`.

Perhaps you meant for `Acc_landingPage_Pom` to extend `DriverInstance` and not define its own `driver` member or perhaps you meant to put `driver = driver2` inside `Acc_landingPage_Pom`'s constructor.

You cannot initialize/construct an `Actions` with a `null` `WebDriver`.

Comment: I've updated my answer after confirming with the questioner what his question is to explain more clearly what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: @mfulton26 If i am removing "Webdriver driver"(Declaring below class name ) from Acc_landingPage_Pom then getting compile time error on actions class line(create a local variable).

Comment: Did you change `public class Acc_landingPage_Pom {` to `public class Acc_landingPage_Pom extends DriverInstance {`?